# mysql - Unable to get all columns with select *

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following 2 tables t1, t2

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
id INT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE t2 (
id INT PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1),(2),(3);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (2),(3),(4);
```

I am running

```
select * from t1 left join t2 using(id);
```

Result:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
+----+
```

On running script:

```
select t1.id, t2.id from t1 left join t2 using(id);
```

Result:

```
+----+------+
| id | id   |
+----+------+
|  1 | NULL |
|  2 |    2 |
|  3 |    3 |
+----+------+
```

select * is supposed to return all the columns, so, why I am not getting 2 rows when I am using select *?

Note: I am using Mysql

Comment: Interestingly  select * from t1 left join t2 using(id); does behave as expected if you substitute the using clause with an on clause (which is the more usual way of joining).

Comment: I tried On clause. It is behaving as expected, so I guess this is something related to behaviour of USING clause.

Comment: This is the default behavior of `using`

Comment: This is one reason why USING is confUSING

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[as doc says:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

> Natural joins and joins with USING, including outer join variants, are processed according to the SQL:2003 standard:
>
> Redundant columns of a NATURAL join do not appear. Consider this set of statements:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (i INT, j INT);
CREATE TABLE t2 (k INT, j INT);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1, 1);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES(1, 1);
SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 USING (j);
```

> column j is named in the USING clause and should appear only once in the output, not twice.

Answer (score 2):

This is the normal behavior of the `USING` clause. Here's a quote from MySQL documentation:

> Similarly, in the second `SELECT` statement, column `j` is named in the `USING` clause and should appear only once in the output, not twice.

([JOIN syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html))

And here's from Wikipedia:

> [...] any columns mentioned in the `USING` list **will appear only once**, with an unqualified name, rather than once for each table in the join.

([JOIN (SQL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL))