# MySQL Performance - JOIN ON vs JOIN USING on multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

Speaking in principle, which one is faster:

```
SELECT FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 INNER JOIN t3 ON t1.c = t2.c = t3.c
```

vs

```
SELECT FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 USING (c) INNER JOIN t3 USING (c)
```

Comment: Please read this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ . Please pay special attention to the section on query performance. Then, please [edit] your question.  If you don't do that, you may as well ask *how long is a journey?*

Comment: Probably  performance are same (not sure 100%) but please also note that `USING` and    `ON` sometimes gives  little bit different results: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45605943/mysql-unable-to-get-all-columns-with-select/45606545#45606545

Comment: I'd have thought that first one would be an error (missing on or using clause for the first join)

Comment: I've tested them

Comment: The two queries are wildly different in what they do (in MySQL, `x = y = z` does not do what you expect).  If you are going to ask a question -- even a hypothetical one -- then try to have queries that make sense.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way for you to tell this would be to look at your [explain plan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html). If you look at both, you'll probably see zero difference.

The `using()` keyword here is simply a shorthand expression. It evaluates to the same thing as your other option, and therefore makes no difference to performance.

Answer (score 0):

The FROM part of any SQL statement is logically processed first before any other part of SQL statement and both statements are joining in the FROM portion (just don't add the join criteria to a WHERE clause).  Assuming both have syntax correct, then the bigger question is whether these are flowing from M:1, M:1 context and whether there are indexes on both primary and foreign keys.  Then run them through a query analyzer to gage the actual performance.